# Google doc viewer api

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I had problem with my spring and Hibernate project.In that i have used amazon infrastructure.My project is online document selling but before customer purchase this document it give them some preview of that document.that preview can be 2-3 pages.

i have used amazon infrastructure for storing file.url is from amazon.Admin can upload book and using s3 bucket and s/w upload it to server.

For book preview i have used google doc viewer it works fine for .pdf and .doc but it creates problem with .xls file.

so can any one suggest the best tool for this type of functionality?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Is free this service in 2021 for comercial or has price link?